# How to override sprockets paths in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to override the path that Sprockets produces in Rails, particularly for the sass helpers.

I've gotten somewhere using various solutions:

a) overriding the image_tag helpers in the views

b) overriding ActionView::AssetPaths compute function

c) including new module in Sass::Script::Functions

But it feels like there should be a much simpler way than doing all this.  Is there a nice way
to decorate the sprockets paths?  I'm doing this because we have some custom url and packaging stuff happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end I found this message buried in sprockets/context.rb

```
Custom asset_path helper is not implemented
Extend your environment context with a custom method.

environment.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
  end
end
```

Which would seem to suggest that Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval would 
allow me to change the asset_path handler, but it didn't seem to work.  I'm not sure if that's my fault or not, as I couldn't find any examples of this.

Currently my hack to get this working is this:

```
  ActionView::AssetPaths.class_eval do
    def compute_public_path(source, dir, options = {})
      my_transform(source)
    end
  end

  Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths.class_eval do
    def compute_public_path(source, dir, options = {})
      my_transform(source)
    end
  end

  ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::AssetPaths.class_eval do
    def compute_public_path(source, dir, options = {})
      my_transform(source)
    end
  end
```

I suspect I don't need all three of these, but I'm not sure.  Anybody who knows their sprockets want to comment on this?